# Youtrack Mailbox Integration with Gmail

Tags: gmail, jetbrains-ide, youtrack

I want to get email from a specific address (gmail) and automatically create issues. And I'm not sure, how to do this.

In youtrack **Mailbox Integration Settings** I click  **Configure New Mailbox Server** and then I don't know what to choose. What parameters should I use to get emails from gmail address

- Protocol:IMAPS
- Host:imap.gmail.com
- Port:993
- Login:mylogin
- Password:mypassword
- Select SSL key: nothing
- Connection timeout:60
- Socket timeout:60

But get `[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)`

there is 2 step verification on this account - maybe that can be a reason of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Which exactly steps of verification does the account have? 
Here you can find a description of mailbox setup parameters: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/2018.1/Mailbox-Integration.html#enable-mailbox-integration

Comment: Verification by mobile phone

Comment: do you mean a code sent by sms or the number of your mobile phone?

Comment: Please try the following:
1. Go to Gmail and allow non-secure application access
2. Login to that mail account and check if there are any blocked attempts to login. If there are any, unblock them and check if it helps.